# Ionic V1.3 - tabs - badge-style with condition <ion-tab>

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic and trying to add condition to badge-style inside `<ion-tab>`

```
<ion-tab title="style"
         icon-on="icon-payment_home" icon-off="icon-payment_home"
         badge-style="badge-assertive"
         badge="(calculateBadgeValue < 100) ? calculateBadgeValue + '%' : '&#10003'">
    <div class="custom-tab-scroll" ng-include src="'...'"></div>
</ion-tab>
```

is it possible to add condition for badge-style? I would like to set css class per condition.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

View:

```
<ion-tab 
  ...
  badge="badge()" 
  badge-style="{{badge() ? 'badge-calm' : 'badge-assertive'}}">
  <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

or

```
<ion-tab 
  ...
  badge="badge()"
  badge-style="{{badgeStyle()}}">
  <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.badge = function(){
  return 3;
};
$scope.badgeStyle = function(){
  return 'badge-assertive';
};
```

[CHECK THE DEMO](http://codepen.io/manzapanza/pen/wGZQLg?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you! the curly braces was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, theoretically you can do it. I advise you to do it in JS (Angular) in order to add your custom class. Don't do it directly in the HTMl file (View).

But, watch out, the attributes for "**ion-tab**" aren't "badge" and "badge-style" anymore. Now it's "**tabBadge**" and "**tabBadgeStyle**".

Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working with Ionic version 1, do you have a solution for this version?

Comment: Check this link for Ionic 1: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionTabs/